# View JVM logs file location on LINUX server

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, agent

We had a Redhat server and I want to view the log file from JVM where it is located in filesystem.

I tried to use VisualVM to connect at this machine, but on this machine is running a weblogic architecture with an ODI12 agent.

I looked for how to investigate the variables of JVM like -XX:+PrintGCDetails and the others and I didn't find anything on this subject.

The question is: Is it possible to force the JVM to write the logs or JVM write default logs?

Comment: what is your question again? I don't get it

Comment: I mean that JVM have default logs into files?

Comment: you mean the place where JVM logs GC logs? is that the question? there is "no default" - you need to enable them to have them

Comment: Ok. The question is how can i enable them?

Comment: that depends on the java version that you use

Comment: java version "1.8.0_271"